# Index screenshots

Tags: spotlight, screen-capture, ocr, indexing

I want to be able to search through text in my screenshots that I made. Prizmo does the OCR feature pretty well and also has an Automator action provided. Unfortunately, though, I have no idea how to implement it in a way that Automator remembers the images filename and renames the document created by Prizmo again. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Search for text in screenshots and rename pictures based on found text?

Answer (score 1):

Evernote can do this for you, it will make text and handwriting searchable.

Comment: i find evernote to be pretty slow and annoying (and most of the time the OCR isn't working all that well either?). maybe i'm the only one but id be grateful for any alternative. thank you anyway for your input!